# Does lodash have a one-line method for calling a function if it exists?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given I have this code:

```
if (_.isFunction(this.doSomething)) {
    this.doSomething();
}
```

Whereby loadingComplete is a directive attribute passed in from a parent controller that may not always be provided, is there a cleaner one-line way to call the method if it exists, without repeating the method name?

Something like:

```
_.call(this, 'doSomething');
```

Comment: What would you expect if `doSomething` isn't a function to call?

Comment: Nothing... hence why I have it wrapped in an if...

Comment: You'd never really be sure if the function gets called. I think that might be very dangerous for your code.

Comment: `function callIt(func, context) { if (typeof func === "function") { func.apply(context || window); } -> callIt(this.doSomething, this);`

Comment: lodash shouldn't be used for _everything_. Stick with the conditional.

Comment: @Andy I already have lodash as a dependency, so if it provides a cleaner way of conditionally calling a function, why not use it?

Comment: This is a solid question with a worthwhile goal.

Comment: Without an actual sequence of such invocations (in which case lodash may fit better, ie. with a map-reduce), I would just do it 'normally'. That said, regardless of if 'using lodash' is appropriate, it is a specific objective question that can be answered.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here, but [`_.attempt`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#attempt) has been around since v3, and will attempt to invoke whatever it is passed-- it can be a property on an object, or just a variable that may or may not contain a function.  The sort of mixed blessing is that it will swallow any error thrown-- so if the container doesn't hold a function it won't blow up the app when it attempts to invoke it, but if you need to handle errors coming from the function this wouldn't work.  I agree it would be nice if there was a true `_.callIfFunction` method.

Answer (score 31):

```
_.result(this, 'doSomething', 'defaultValueIfNotFunction')
```

Comment: How do you pass arguments to `doSomething` if not whats the alternative when you have an object of objects with the same property but need to pass an argument

Comment: Nevermind `_.forIn(objects, function(object) { _.invoke(object, 'method', args) });`

Answer (score 14):

As of version 4.0.0 lodash provides a method called `invoke`: https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#invoke

```
var object = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b }
};

_.invoke(object, 'add', 1, 2);
// => 3

_.invoke(object, 'oops');
// => undefined
```

Note that it will still explode if for some reason there is something *other* than a function at the key you provide.

Comment: +1 `_.invoke` is better designed for OPs use case than `_.result` because it allows the passing of arguments, and it's just named more appropriately. `_.result` seems to be more for calling simple getters that need access to `this`.

Answer (score 5):

Newer Javascript / Typescript version supports it natively

```
const result = someInterface.nullableMethod?.();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

(See bottom of the page for native browser support)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly but you can use [result](https://lodash.com/docs#result):

```
_.result({fn: this.doSomething}, 'fn');
```

Comment: It is ugly, and if I saw that in some code I was reviewing I wouldn't have a clue what it did. That's no reflection on you, just that I think the OP is wrong in using lodash to solve this non-problem.

Comment: it's a matter of preference, I think it's not ugly if you have an object holding either strings or getters (which are simple functions without parameters) and still want to get the value (and even a default value)

Answer (score 0):

if `this.doSomething` is either a function or undefined/falsy, then:

```
this.doSomething && this.doSomething();
```

is a commonly used pattern.

Comment: "without repeating the method name"

Comment: Yeah, that's a dumb requirement.  `var x = this.doSomething; x && x();`

Comment: @James, it's not a dumb requirement..... It's clear I just want a simple terse way of conditionally calling a function. I like clean, short code. Sorry if that offends you.

Comment: `_.isFunction(this.doSomething) && this.doSomething();` is terse.

Comment: Doesn't offend me at all, but the best way to do this involves checking that x exists (or is a function), and then calling x.  Two different operations on x, hence the need to repeat the method name.  Anything that pretends to only use the method name once is wrapping its check + call in some kind of function.

Answer (score -5):

```
if (_.isFunction(this.doSomething)) {
    this.doSomething();
}
```

In one line:

```
if (_.isFunction(this.doSomething)) this.doSomething();
```

Comment: "without repeating the method name"

Comment: Discarding the braces does not make it a "one liner", it makes it poorly formatted. Many common js linters would complain about your "optimization"